# How to expand a variable

Tags: metapost

I am not sure about the title of this question but here is the context.

Let's say I have two colors defined as follow

```
color red      ; red      = (1, 0, 0) ;
color lightred ; lightred = (1, .5, .5) ;
```

and now, let's say... I want to, respectively, `draw` and `fill` a path with, respectively, `red` and `lightred` like so

```
def drawerfiller(expr p, c) =
  fill p withcolor lightred ;
  draw p withcolor red ;
enddef ;
```

Can I use the variable `c` by expanding (?) it in order to have something like

```
def drawerfiller(expr p, c) =
  fill p withcolor light{c} ;
  draw p withcolor {c} ;
enddef ;
```

?

Comment: It will depend on what is doing the expanding, I think. In TikZ, given `\newcommand\cred{red}\definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.9}`, then `... /.style = {draw, circle, \cred, fill=light\cred, inner sep = 0pt, ...}` certainly works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do calculations on colours. Try something like this:

```
def drawerfiller(expr p, c) =
  fill p withcolor 1/2[c, background];
  draw p withcolor c;
enddef;
```

or perhaps, for your particular example:

```
def drawerfiller(expr p, c) =
  fill p withcolor (c + (1/2, 1/2, 1/2));
  draw p withcolor c ;
enddef ;
```

You do not need to "expand" the variables explicitly, so no need for curly brackets here (or anywhere in MP actually).

(The second example assumes you are using the RGB colours.)

If you wanted to be more sophisticated, you could define your colours with suffixes:

```
color shade.light, shade.medium;
shade.medium = (1/2, 0, 0);
shade.light = (1, 1/2, 1/2);
```

and explicitly define the second parameter as a suffix rather than an expression:

```
vardef fillerdrawer(expr p)(suffix s) = 
  fill p withcolor s.light; 
  draw p withcolor s.medium;
enddef;
```

Equally correctly, you could also write:

```
vardef fillerdrawer(expr p)(text s) = 
  fill p withcolor s.light; 
  draw p withcolor s.medium;
enddef;
```

**What's going on here?**  If a parameter is defined as an `expr`, then MP will evaluate it and put it into a special “capsule” token that will be substituted for the parameter in the replacement text. This is the usual case.

But in this example if you made `s` an `expr`, and passed `shade` as the value of the `s` it would be evaluated as an unknown numeric, so you would get an error after `withcolor` because `<<unknown numeric capsule>>.light` is not a `color` variable.

On the other hand, if you define `s` as a `suffix` or `text` parameter, MP will just put the tokens into a plain token list without any further evaluation.  It will then use this token list to substitute `s` in the macro definition.

So now when you pass `shade` to the macro, `s` becomes a token list with the value `shade` and `withcolor s.light` will expand to `withcolor shade.light` as required.

At this point you may ask yourself “what is the difference between `text` and `suffix` parameters?”.  The answer is “not much” except that any subscripts in a `suffix` parameter will be evaluated to numeric tokens, but in a `text` parameter they would be passed on unchanged.

Chapters 18, 19, and 20 of [*The Metafont Book*](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/abcde.html#mfbk) are the primary reference for this level of macro detail.

As a complete (working) example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

color shade.light, shade.medium;
shade.medium = (1/2, 0, 0);
shade.light = (1, 1/2, 1/2);
    
vardef fillerdrawer(expr p)(suffix s) = 
  fill p withcolor s.light; 
  draw p withcolor s.medium;
enddef;

beginfig(1);
fillerdrawer(unitsquare scaled 20, shade);
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` (or adapt it for plain MP) to get:

[image]

Note that as a bit of syntactic kindness, MP allows `,` instead of `)(` when you call a macro defined like this.

But there is a limit to how clever you need to make things like that.  The more complex it is, the harder it is to remember.  Part of the beauty of plain MP is that is simple, and easy to learn.  (Apart from the subtleties of variable suffixes and subscripts... :-).

Comment: OK, you were quicker than me, so I will remove my answer. :)

Comment: I have tried your sophisticated answer but it returns an error: `<error> shade.medium […] Equation cannot be performed (numeric=color) […] <error> (0.5,0,0) […] <to be read again> ;`. Do you know what is happening here?

Comment: Apologies, I was in a rush, and have muddled up suffixes and subscripts (not for the first time...)  -- see amendments.